# Window aggregation or normal aggregation?

Tags: function, apache-spark, window

My table has 8107 rows in total.

suppose I'm finding "avg(altitude)" group by "country" on a column with Window  I get output :

```
avg = ap.withColumn('avg_alt',mean(ap.altitude).over(Window.partitionBy(ap.country)))
```

o/p: 8107 rows

same with spark.sql-

```
select avg(altitude) from table group by country
```

o/p:240 rows

Which is the correct output?

Should I use window or normal sql ?

Both are technically right but window gives for each row

Answer (score 0):

Both outputs are correct, they only differ in the output format. As you mentioned correctly the window approach will attach the average altitude to each row of your dataframe whereas the SQL group-by approach will only have the average altitude per country.
In most cases you only want to use the grouped and aggregated results (e.g. if you  want to plot it, or display the highest/lowest countries etc.)
If you want to do further computations, the window-approach should be best (e.g. if you want to find the locations that have the maximum difference to the average altitude).